# How to use operating system ability of copy and paste using eclipse RCP?

Tags: windows, eclipse-rcp, java-11

I'm using a custom CopyHandler and a PasteHandler in my Editor that displays a NatTable. The idea is to enable this CopyHandler if one or multiple cells are selected. But it doesn't work correctly, when a cell is in edit mode and only a part of the cell content is selected. The reason is that the cells don't have a selection.

The many answers on SO have different preconditions that don't apply here.

When I return `false` in the canExecute method, the Operating Systems ability to copy and paste is used. This is exactly what I want, but I need to trigger it programmatically, because my Application has ToolItems for Cut, Copy and Paste which will be disabled, if canExecute returns false.

So my idea is to implement different behaviors in my CopyHandler:
If one or multiple cells of my table are selected: Use the custom implementation.
If only one cell is selected and that one is in edit mode: Use OS mechanism to copy/paste.

So how can I make use of the operating systems ability to copy and paste text?

My CopyHandler is triggered by CTRL+C

```
@Creatable
@TargetCommand (IWorkbenchCommandConstants.EDIT_COPY)
public class MyCopyHandler {
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand you question correctly. Because you are mixing things up. The NatTable CopyHandler is called when you copy a selected cell in NatTable. You are then in the context of NatTable. If you copy selected content in an open editor, you left the context of NatTable and execute a copy operation in the SWT context of the opened control (I suppose the Text control). So actually, what you want to achieve should be already the default behavior. And it shouldn't be possible to programmatically copy content of an editor, as the focus lost will close the cell editor.

Comment: I can see my CopyHandler being called when I hit Ctrl+C on a selection inside the nattable's cell. So what you are saying is, this is already a mistake, because I shouldn't be in the context of NatTable?

Comment: Sorry, this is confusing. The code you now pasted is a copy handler for RCP. This one should be called when you copy something in an open NatTable editor (I think this is what you mean with "selection in nattable's cell", as I am not sure what you mean here). To copy something in NatTable if you have only selected some cells, you need to use the NatTable copy mechanism. By default, this one is using the system clipboard. But if you want to customize this, you need to dig deeper in the NatTable code, not RCP in general.

Comment: This CopyHandler is called both when copying something in an open NatTable editor and when copying mutliple selected cells. I can distinguish those cases by checking that only one cell is selected and the active cell is in edit mode. For this case I want to trigger the standard SWT behavior instead of using the rest of the execute method.

Comment: So the question is not related to NatTable, but about how to programmatically trigger the OS copy action from a custom copy handler? Then I don't know. Would need to check the sources or debug the copy process to find the right place.

Comment: not related to nattable, but nattable might bring a solution.

Comment: You use the SWT `Clipboard` to do the OS Copy/Paste - see the "Clipboard" section in https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/